# Synaptics touchpad not working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: touchpad

Im using an HP 15-D017cl notebook pc and after installing ubuntu 14.04 LTS, my touchpad stopped working. it works in windows 8.1, but in ubuntu, it has never worked since the start. after going through terminal and using the sudo apt-get command for the xorg synaptics driver, it still didnt work. when i go to terminal and use the synclient command, it reports back that the synaptics driver is not loaded. please help, i dont want to keep having to use a usb mouse.